# Is the direction derivatives of (orthonormal) normal vector(s) in its own direction in the tangent space?

Tags: differential-geometry, jacobian, tangent-spaces

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $d$ embedded in dimension $D>d$. Let $n_1,\dotsc, n_K$ be any orthonormal basis for $N_xM := T_xM^{\perp}$, the orthogonal complement of the tangent space of $M$ at $x$. Let $D[n_i]$ be the Jacobian of the vector field $n_i$ with respect to $x\in \mathbb{R}^D$. We assume that the $n_i$ are defined on a neighborhood of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^D$.

**Question**:
Is the vector $v_i(x) = D[n_i(x)]n_i(x)$ in the tangent space of $M$ at $x$?, i.e. $D[n_i]n_i \in T_xM$ for any $i$. (We are suppressing the notation $n_i(x)$ for $n_i$, out of laziness).

**Partial Results**:
If $K=1$ the answer is yes. That is because we can easily prove for any $i$ that $n_i \perp v_i$ and if $K=1$ then there is only one normal spanning the orthogonal complement of the tangent space, so if we perpendicular to it, we must be tangent to the manifold, by definition of orthogonal complement.

For $K>1$, it eludes me. Here is what I have shown.

1. $n_j^T v_i = -n_i^T D[n_j]n_i$,
2. $n_i \perp D[n_i]u$ for any $u\in T_xM$, and
3. $n_j^T D[n_i]u = -n_i^T D[n_j]u$ for any $u\in T_xM$.

**Possible counterexample**:
After thinking for some time, I began to suspect this is not true. Consider the space curve $\phi(x) = (x, x^2, 1-x)^T$. This has tangent $\phi'(x) = (1, 2x, -1)^T$. From which we can obtain normals via Gram-Schmidt,
$$n_1 = [2x, -1, 0]^T/\sqrt{1+4x^2}$$
and
$$n_2 = [3x^2, 6x^3, -(1+4x^2)]^T/\sqrt{(1+4x^2)(1+4x^2+9x^4)}.$$
And Jacobians
$$D[n_1] = \begin{bmatrix}
2h(x)^{-3} & 0 & 0\\
4xh(x)^{-3} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $h(x) = \sqrt{1+4x^2}$.
It follows that
$$n_2^T D[n_1]n_1 = \frac{12x^3}{(1+4x^2)\sqrt{1+8x^2+25x^4+36x^6}}\neq 0$$
for $x\neq 0$.

So if this is sound, then the question becomes: well *when* is it true, because it holds for, say, $\phi_1(x)=(x, 3x, \sin(x))^T$ and $(x,3x, x^3)^T$, but not $\phi_2(x) = (x, 3x, e^x)^T$.

I'm a beginner in anything related to differential geometry, so I apologize if there is something basic I am missing. I have found it one of the harder subjects to self-study compared to others I have tried.

Comment: This is the analogue for the normal bundle of a connection on the tangent bundle. Just as there’s no reason for $\nabla_{e_i}e_i$ to be zero in the tangent bundle case, the same holds for the normal connection. Do you recognize the condition that $e_i$ is parallel in its own direction?

Comment: @TedShifrin I reviewed ch. 2 of Do Carmo and will try to unpack this. $\nabla_{n_j}n_i :=D[n_i]n_j$ satisfies the three properties of an affine connection, i.e. that $\nabla_x v$ is linear in $x$, additive in $v$ and satisfies scalar-vector product rule in $v$. So it is an affine connection on the normal bundle? A vector field $v$ is parallel in the direction of $x$ when $\nabla_x v = 0$. If so, then $v_i\in T_xM$ certainly if $\nabla_{n_i} n_i=0$ but this is not always so. Or am I way off? If not, isn't this condition not necessary--can't we have $\nabla_{n_i} n_i\neq 0$ but $v_i\in T_xM$?

Comment: It’s an affine connection on the normal bundle once you follow the directional derivative by a projection onto the normal space. As with the tangential case, the “other” component (here, the tangential) is a second fundamental form for the sub-bundle. You can think of it this way: The entire covariant derivative maps $TM\oplus NM\to TM\oplus NM$ and there are four block “submatrices” to consider.